# Add multiple products to cart from wishlist through check box in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, wishlist

I Want to add multiple products to cart from wishlist through checkbox, such as selected products along with their quantity are transferred to cart and the selected items are removed from the wishlist

Comment: Share the code what have you tried

Comment: hi vishwas,i tried to convert magento1 code to magento2

Comment: can u help me out how to work around it.

Comment: add code to your question with issue that you are facing then people here can actually help you